# How to insert data to mysql with jdbc and jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have some table in mysql with columns: applicant_id,profession_id, last_name, first_name, entrance_year.
I have a problem with insert data to that table.
My class applicant:

```
public class Applicant extends Entity {

    private long professionId;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int entranceYear;

    public Applicant() {
    }

    public Applicant(long professionId, String lastName, String firstName, int entranceYear) {
        this.professionId = professionId;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.entranceYear = entranceYear;
    }

    public long getProfessionId() {
        return professionId;
    }

    public void setProfessionId(long professionId) {
        this.professionId = professionId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getEntranceYear() {
        return entranceYear;
    }

    public void setEntranceYear(int entranceYear) {
        this.entranceYear = entranceYear;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Applicant{" +
                "professionId=" + professionId +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", entranceYear=" + entranceYear +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Entity {

    protected long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Next, my class that have connection to mysql:

```
public enum ApplicantDBProvider {

    INSTANCE;

    private Connection connection;

    private ApplicantDBProvider() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_applicant", "root", "toor");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
    }

    public Applicant getApplicant(long applicantId) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Applicant applicant = null;
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM applicant WHERE applicant_id=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, (int) applicantId);

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                applicant = new Applicant();
                applicant.setEntranceYear(resultSet.getInt("entrance_year"));
                applicant.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                applicant.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                applicant.setProfessionId(resultSet.getInt("profession_id"));
                applicant.setId(resultSet.getInt("applicant_id"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        }

        return applicant;
    }

    public List<Applicant> getApplicants() throws Exception {
        Statement statement = null;
        List <Applicant> applicants = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM applicant");
            Applicant applicant = new Applicant();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                applicant.setEntranceYear(resultSet.getInt("entrance_year"));
                applicant.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                applicant.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                applicant.setProfessionId(resultSet.getInt("profession_id"));
                applicant.setId(resultSet.getInt("applicant_id"));
                applicants.add(applicant);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        return applicants;
    }

    public void saveApplicant(Applicant applicant) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            if (applicant.getId() == -1) {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO applicant (first_name, last_name, profession_id, entrance_year) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

                preparedStatement.setString(1, applicant.getFirstName());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, applicant.getLastName());
                preparedStatement.setLong(3, (long) applicant.getProfessionId());
                preparedStatement.setInt(4, (int) applicant.getEntranceYear());

            } else {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE applicant SET first_name=?, last_name=?, profession_id=?, entrace_year=?  WHERE applicant_id=?");

                preparedStatement.setString(1, applicant.getFirstName());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, applicant.getLastName());
                preparedStatement.setLong(3, (long) applicant.getProfessionId());
                preparedStatement.setInt(4, (int) applicant.getEntranceYear());
                preparedStatement.setInt(5, (int) applicant.getId());
            }
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteApplicant(long applicantId) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM applicant WHERE applicant_id=?");

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, (int) applicantId);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My class that add to table applicant data:

```
public class SaveApplicantCommand implements ICommand {

    private ApplicantDBProvider provider = ApplicantDBProvider.INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {

            Applicant applicant = new Applicant();

        applicant.setFirstName(request.getParameter("first_name"));
        applicant.setLastName(request.getParameter("last_name"));
        applicant.setProfessionId(request.getDateHeader("profession_id"));
        applicant.setEntranceYear(request.getIntHeader("entrance_year"));

        if (request.getParameter("applicant_id") != null) {
            applicant.setId(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("applicant_id")));
        }

        try {
            provider.saveApplicant(applicant);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("error", e);
            return "pages/error.jsp";
        }

        return "controller?command=applicants";
    }
```

After that class, i have first question. My setProfessionId and setEntranceYear, is long and int primitive datatypes. Is correct to use getDateHeader and getIntHeader in that code ? Because getParameter work only with String data type.
Next, two my jsp and that all:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Applicants</h1>
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${applicants.size() == 0}">
    <p><c:out value="No applicants yet"></c:out></p>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Profession ID</th>
        <th>Entrance Year</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <c:forEach items="${applicants}" var="applicant">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${applicant.getId()}"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${applicant.getFirstName()}"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${applicant.getLastName()}"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${applicant.getProfessionId()}"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${applicant.getEntranceYear()}"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="controller?command=deleteApplicant&id=${applicant.getId()}">Delete</a>
            <a href="controller?command=editApplicant&id=${applicant.getId()}">Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<a href="controller?command=addApplicant">Add new applicant</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And next jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add application</h1>

<form method="post" action="controller?command=saveApplication">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Profession ID</th>
      <th>Entrance Year</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${application ne null}">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" value="${application.getFirstName()}"/>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" value="${application.getLastName()}"/>
      <input type="text" name="profession_id" value="${application.getProfessionId()}"/>
      <input type="text" name="entrance_year" value="${application.getEntranceYear()}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="application_id" value="${application.getId()}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""/>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""/>
      <input type="text" name="profession_id" value=""/>
      <input type="text" name="entrance_year" value=""/>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sorry that i have a lot of code, but i want to show for you all my problem. After compile code, i have a page in tomcat, when i have four forms, when i can write data. But, after put "enter" on my keyboard, i cant insert that data types in sql table. I think, maybe need add button ? It is easy, but i dont know how to do that. Please, help.
There are two questions:

1. When i have long and int, is correct to use `getDateHeader` and `getIntHeader` in that code ? Because `getParameter` work only with String data type.
2. How to insert data in my table ?

Thank for your attention. And sorry, that i have a lot of code.

Comment: you don't have a submit button for your form. Before closing the form tag add `<input type=submit value=Add>`

Comment: thanks. second question is solved. but i have error, when i put "Sumbit". May be answer for first question solve that problem.

Comment: You will find the data in the request body itself, and not in its header. You should use getParameter and cast it to long and int, should do a check first if it is int and long there.

Comment: like `applicant.setEntranceYear( Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("entrance_year")) );`

Comment: and `applicant.setProfessionId( Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("profession_id")) );`

Comment: thanks, but i have, java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It is not clear to me what your current problem is, pleased edit your question to 1) remove the problem that has been solved, 2) reduce the code to the minimum necessary, 3) better explain the problem you are facing, including stacktraces of exceptions if any.